# Building A Custom QTreeView with objects using C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

Ok, So I am a bit of a noob to all subjects contained within this post. New to C++ and new to Qt. That being said I have done a ton of reading on the subject and have been working at this for quite some time. Perhaps I am not wrapping my head around this correctly, or perhaps I am going completely the wrong direction.  Please help and advise me as to how I should approach this issue!

I am building a QtreeView based on the following class structure: (only important members shown)

```
Class ScenarioManager               // singleton
{
Qvector<object_A*> *AllObjectA's
}

Class Object_A
{
QString             name
Qvector<double>     numSet          // 3 values inside
Qvector<double>     numSet2         // 2 values inside.
QString             type
Qvector<Object_B*>  AllObjectB's    //Object_B is an interface class with
                                    //purely virtual functions
}

Class Object_C : Object_B
{
QString     name
bool        isTypeObjectC
Object_F*   exact
}

Class Object_D : Object_B
{
String      name
bool        isTypeObjectC
Object_F*   min 
Object_F*   max
QVector<Object_F*>  AllObjectF's    // setOfAllMins/Maxes that subdivide the
                                    // region between min and max.
}

Class Object_F
{
double      value
}
```

I have followed the example in creating the tree view that can be found here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html

and successfully been able to make the view I want Which looks like below:

```
|__name__|__type__|__f-range__|__allobjectf_|     // header data
|
|Object_A1-name __Object_A1_Type     // under name and type fields
|   |
|   AllObjectC's                     // under name
|   |   |
|   |   Object_C1_name               // under name
|   |   Object_C2_name
|   |       |______exact.value       // under f-range
|   AllObjectD's
|       |
|       Object_D1_name
|       Object_D2_name
|           |_____min.value '-' max.value  // under f-range
|                  |__AllObjectF[0].min '-' AllObjectF[0].max//under allObjF
|                  |__AllObjectF[1].min '-' AllObjectF[1].max
|                  |__AllObjectF[2].min '-' AllObjectF[2].max
|                               
|Object_A2-name __Object_A2_Type....(repeat)
```

My issue is that I still need to be able to accomplish 2 more tasks that for the life of me I can't seem to complete using that sample (in the link posted) as a template.

My code mimics the sample in the link nearly identically! the model class iterates over my scenariomanager member vector, constructs tree items, and rather grossly builds a the TreeView with strings in a fashion nearly identical to the SetupModelData function.

This is all well and good, except I need to do the following.

1. select an item in the tree, click a delete button

   - when this is done the item needs to be deleted from the treeview (and its children)
   - and the item needs to be removed entirely from the original scenario manager.
2. select an item in the tree, and be able to add an appropriate child to that object.

   - needs to show in the tree view
   - and needs to be added in the appropriate location to the scenario manager

For the life of me I cant figure out how to do this, I have tried a laundry list of ideas but I have just not been able to succeed. what would be the best method to go about this?

Is there any way to get more then just the QVarient Strings out of the treeview? is it possible to get a pointer to the actual tree node that created the tree? If I could do that I could just modify the tree nodes to be created with pointers to the scenario manager objects that created them and manipulate things that route.

But what is the best method to proceed? I have not been able to find anything that specifically outlines what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You're not building a view, you're building a *model*.

Comment: It sure feels like I am building a view, I know I am not, but my model class by and large feels like i built a view..... I know what you mean though! Now the trick is to get it to do everything I want it to do.

Comment: Hi Shootin4Aces, if you found a solution please add it as answer, don't put answers into the question.

Comment: will do! was not thinking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to accomplish what I needed to, though I am still quite convinced it was not the best methodology. Better Suggestions are welcome!!

Ultimately I modified my treenode class to have a member field:

```
QObject* dataSource;
```

this pointer is set during the model creation for each tree item. you can then access the original data source that created the model via a method like this

```
QModelIndex anIndex = ui->treeView->currentIndex();

if(anIndex.isValid())
{
    STreeItem *item = static_cast<STreeItem*>(anIndex.internalPointer());

    ObjectType* obj = static_cast<ObjectType*>(item->getDataSourcePointer());        
}
```

I hope that this helps someone else in a similar situation, thanks for the ideas and guidance!

Answer (score 0):

what treemodel class are you using?

i still cannot comment :(  thats why i am posting this comment in the answering section,, hope you guys dont mind.

basically, your treemodel-item class will need the function to support deleting and appending items.

for example

```
void ItemClass::insertChild(int row, itemClass *item){
    item->m_parent = this;
    m_children.insert(row, item);
}
```

so if you have an item and you want to add another item to it on row 5 for exanmple

item->insertChild(5, anotherItem)

the first line in the function will make item the parent of anotherItem and then it will add anotherItem to the list of children of item on row 5 in this case

to get a pointer to the currently selected item i would do:

```
QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole && role != Qt::EditRole)
        return QVariant();

    TreeItem *item = getItem(index);

    pointervariable = item; <<== pointervariable is inside your modelclass

    return item->data(index.column());
}
```

Comment: model view setup is nearly identical to the sample provided here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html  I have a tree item class and model basically identical to that! my model inherits from QAbstractItemModel ... it is bacially identical to that sample

Comment: the mentioned Scenario Manager class is outside of these 2 classes

Comment: allright, try checking out the "Editable Treemodel Example" which can be found inside Qt in the Examples section. I think it has everything you need

Comment: Is there any way to get more then just the QVarient Strings out of the treeview? is it possible to get a pointer to the actual tree node that created the tree from the currently selected index??

Comment: @Shootin4Aces  so basically you want a pointer to the object that is currently selected in the view?

Comment: Editable treemodel example allows for the strings to be edited within the model/view, but this view is only a partial view of the data displayed to the user and is more complicated then the strings displayed to the user. I could be doing this all very wrong and be making incorrectly.... currently my qvarients are string lists that are string representations of the objects data aspects i want displayed in the view

Comment: as I said a newb at this stuff so I likely went about this the wrong way... but yes, having a pointer to the object that is currently selected in the tree view would be awesome

Comment: if I had that I could add another data member to the tree items that points to the object that created them within the scenario manager

Comment: what i would do is: in the data function inside the treemodel, i would add a line that copies the pointer to a pointervariable in your treemodel.. that way you dont have to mess with the model, because you do want to return the QVariant, that way your model can store different kinds of data

Comment: can you outline that a little more to make sure I am understanding that properly?  I think I have just framed this whole thing incorrectly

Comment: the way i provided could be very dangerous tho,, that function will be called even when you hover over items in the view,, and everytime you hover or click on an item,, that item will be stored inside the variable... so if you want to append to an item,, but you accidently move your mouse over another item,, the pointer will change

Comment: still, take a look at the editable treemodel application,,, in the MainWindow.cpp in the insertChild() method... it grabs the qmodelindex of the currently selected item, then it uses it to get the actual item,, you could use that

Comment: thanks for the help, with everything you said I found a way to do it (stealing an idea from that example and meshing it with my own). While it may be ugly, it works!!! +1